# Vertical bar/rule table alignment

Tags: tables, rules

Would anyone know how to set up a vertical bar in the table so it is proportional at both ends of the table?

[image]

Code:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{p{0.00\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.0\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}@{\hspace{5pt}}R}
& Instructor of record...
& Introduce...
& Demonstrate...
& Develop...
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to TeX.SX! N.B.: You are not comparing the distance above the top of the I with the distance below the bottom of, for example, the p

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to insert a strut of appropriate height as the difference you notice really depends on what the `tabular` contents. Below I've inserted a `.9\normalbaselineskip` strut which increases the height of the first line every so slightly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{p{0pt}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.5\linewidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}@{\hspace{5pt}}R}
  \rule{0pt}{.9\normalbaselineskip}
  & Instructor of record for \ldots \\
  & Introduce basic principles \ldots \\
  & Demonstrate engineering \ldots \\
  & Develop syllabus, \ldots
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```